# Error unused argument (invisible) in CA in r (FactoMineR)

Tags: r

I use the following code:

```
library(FactoMineR)
women_work=read.table("http://factominer.free.fr/classical-methods/datasets/women_work.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep="\t")
```

When I use the following command:
res.ca.col = CA(women_work[,1:3])
I get the graph. However, when I run:

```
> res.ca.rows = CA(women_work[,1:3], invisible="col")
Error in CA(women_work[, 1:3], invisible = "col") : 
  unused argument (invisible = "col")
```

I get an error. Same for

```
> res.ca.col = CA(women_work[,1:3], invisible="row") 
Error in CA(women_work[, 1:3], invisible = "row") : 
  unused argument (invisible = "row")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invisible` is not a valid parameter of `CA` function, but it is for `plot.CA`

From the `FactoMineR` documentation:

```
CA Usage: 
CA(X, ncp = 5, row.sup = NULL, col.sup = NULL,
      quanti.sup=NULL, quali.sup = NULL, graph = TRUE,
      axes = c(1,2), row.w = NULL, excl=NULL)
```

and:

```
plot.CA Usage:
plot(x, axes = c(1, 2),
xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL,
invisible = c("none","row","col","row.sup","col.sup","quali.sup"),
...etc. )
```

Here `x` in the `plot()` would take a `CA` object. So you would write something like:

```
res.ca.rows = CA(women_work[,1:3])
plot(res.ca.rows, invisible="col")
```